# Passing function with bound this causes diffing without needing to render

Tags: reactjs

```
class A extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log("Hello from the other side");
  }

  render() {
   <B onClick={::this.handleClick}/>
  }
}

class B extends React.Component() {
  render() {
    return <div>Useless stuff/>
  }
}
```

When A renders B it passes handleClick function with bound this. This causes that previousProps.onClick !== nextProps.onClick because binding this will create new function every time. How to prevent this? I could use "shouldComponentUpdate" but is there any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the method inside the render method, bind the function inside of the constructor, like this:

```
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log("Hello from the other side");
  }

  render() {
   <B onClick={this.handleClick}/>
  }
}

class B extends React.Component() {
  render() {
    return <div>Useless stuff/>
  }
}
```

you could also use `autobind` from core-decorators like so:

```
import {autobind} from "cure-decorators"

@autobind
class A extends React.Component {      
  handleClick() {
    console.log("Hello from the other side");
  }

  render() {
   <B onClick={this.handleClick}/>
  }
}

class B extends React.Component() {
  render() {
    return <div>Useless stuff/>
  }
}
```

if you are using decorators.